# Re-create Twitter like following in Javascript/PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, twitter

In my application, I have users and groups, each user can follow other users  or follow an entire group and its users.

I would like to know if anyone knows of any framework/typical workflow/example as to how this should be organized.

I am aware you can have a table keeping track of who is following who. But I would like to know if there is anything more sophisticated already established.

Comment: confused, are you looking for anything related to twitter or the twitter api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type of "frameworks" do you want?
I would recommend mostly playing around and doing research for your own answer but I can provide a few links that may help.

Looking at a few Social Network frames might be what you want and on the idea of a specific script, no,I don't know any, but ripping and analyzing a script will help also help you learn a thing or two and with brainstorming, it will really put you on your way.

As a tip, which coming from me you would of figured now, when making a question, its nice to maybe give an example of what you want or example of a code, that way the specific can be targeted and solutions given

[Google Search](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=Social%20networking%20frameworks) This search gives a few social networking sites.
I would also recommend Dolphin a free social networking you can have alook at.

Cheers 
James